# How do I assign a std::function type to sigevent.sigev_notify_function (POSIX timers)

Tags: c++, c++11, posix

I'm using a POSIX timer to call a function that is defined with std::function template:

```
typedef std::function<void (union sigval)> functionCbType;
```

I get the following error in assignment to field sigev_notify_function of struct sigevent:

error: cannot convert ‘functionCbType {aka std::function}’ to ‘void (*)(sigval_t) {aka void (*)(sigval)}’ in assignment
     se.sigev_notify_function = callcbk;

```
functionCbType callcbk;
...
struct sigevent se;
se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
se.sigev_notify_function = callcbk;
se.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

int status = timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &se, &timer_id);
```

se.sigev_notify_function expects

```
void       (*sigev_notify_function) (union sigval);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: [target()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target), maybe?

Comment: You need to use a pointer to the actual function.

Answer (score 1):

A well designed C callback API lets you pass a value to the callback function.  This lets you have stateful callbacks.

In this case, `union sigval` is a union of an `int` and a `void*`.  You are supposed to stick your state in either of those two.

`std::function<Sig>` can store state, so you need to pass that state through.

A `std::function` is not a function pointer.  In order to pass it to a C function callback API, you need to wrap it up and pass it as the `void*` portion.

```
struct sig_cb {
  void(* function)(sigval_t);
  void* pvoid;
};
sig_cb make_signal_callback( std::function<void()>* pf ) {
  return {
    [](sigval_t v) { (*static_cast<std::function<void()>*>(v.sival_ptr))(); },
    pf
  };
}
```

then modify your code:

```
functionCbType callcbk;
...
struct sigevent se;
auto cb = make_signal_callback(&callcbk);
se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
se.sigev_notify_function = cb.function;
se.sigev_value.sival_ptr = cb.pvoid;
se.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

int status = timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &se, &timer_id);
```

and it should work.  Naturally the lifetime of your `std::function` must be managed separately.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sigevent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html) structures `sigev_notify_function` is not expecting a `std::function` object, it is expecting a function pointer:

```
void       (*sigev_notify_function) (union sigval);
```

A `std::function` object can be created implicitly from a function pointer, but the reverse is not possible. You must use a pointer to the actual function.

You can achieve this by using `callcbk.target<void(*)(union sigval)>()` to get a pointer to the original function pointer, but then `callcbk` is somewhat pointless.

Comment: You need to pass a template argument to `target()`, e.g., `callcbk.target<void(*)(union sigval)>`, and this will only work if the stored object was a pointer to such function.

Comment: Thanks, I get the point.
Anyway I still get an error:
se.sigev_notify_function = callcbk.target<void(*)(union sigval)>();


error: cannot convert ‘void (**)(sigval)’ to ‘void (*)(sigval_t) {aka void (*)(sigval)}’ in assignment
     se.sigev_notify_function = callcbk.target<void(*)(union sigval)>();

Comment: @abacus You need to dereference because `.target()` returns a pointer to the target, so a pointer to a pointer to a function: `se.sigev_notify_function = *callcbk.target<void(*)(union sigval)>()`. But how do you create the function in the first place?